# How to enumerate all named captures in RegexKit?

Tags: objective-c, regex, cocoa

I recently wanted use regex in Cocoa app. But I found that Cocoa does not include a regex class. So I decided to use RegexKit (OgreKit is good, but I don't know why it did not run fine on my OSX 10.6.4 x86_64).

I have a file content like:

```
12:20:30 - 01:20:30
some text
11:20:30 - 04:20:30
some text
```

And I want to pick up all time values and text values.I found this example code in a guide:

```
NSString *entireMatchString = NULL, *totalString = NULL, *dollarsString = NULL, *centsString = NULL;
NSString *regexString = @"owe:\\s*\\$?(?<total>(?<dollars>\\d+)\\.(?<cents>\\d+))";

[@"You owe: 1234.56 (tip not included)" getCapturesWithRegexAndReferences:regexString,@"$0", &entireString,@"${total}", &totalString,@"${dollars}", &dollarsString,@"${cents}",&centsString,nil];

// entireString  = @"owe: 1234.56";
// totalString   = @"1234.56";
// dollarsString = @"1234";
// centsString   = @"56";
```

So I wrote a regex string

```
NSString *regexString = @"\\s*\\n*(?<start>\\d\\d:\\d\\d:\\d\\d*)\\s*-\\s*(?<end>\\d\\d:\\d\\d:\\d\\d*)\\s*\\n*(?<text>.*)
```

and it worked fine, but it only works once. I need to pick up all named captures, like we do in Ogrekit, e.g.:

```
OGRegularExpression *regex = [OGRegularExpression regularExpressionWithString:@"<video src=\"(?<imageURL>.+)\".+>"
 options:OgreCaptureGroupOption
 syntax:OgreRubySyntax
 escapeCharacter:OgreBackslashCharacter];

NSArray *matches = [regex allMatchesInString:@"<video src=\"http://test.com/hello.jpg\">"];

if (matches != nil && ([matches count] == 1))
{
 OGRegularExpressionMatch *match = [matches objectAtIndex: 0];
 NSString *result = [match substringNamed:@"ImageURL"];
 // : http://test.com/hello.jpg
}
```

It's easy to find all named capture values from a matches array. Does someone know how to do in RegexKit? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation under [Enumerating all the Matches in a String by a Regular Expression](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/Documentation/RegexKitProgrammingGuide.html#NSStringAdditions_EnumeratingalltheMatchesinaStringbyaRegularExpression). Specifically, you want to learn about the [RKEnumerator](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/Documentation/RKEnumerator.html) class.

Comment: thank you.very useful.and one more question.in nsstring addtions . RKEnumerator *matchEnumerator = [textContent matchEnumeratorWithRegex:regexString]; textContent is a nsstring object. i couldnot find method mathEnumeratorXXX  with options.  so i couldn't special match option with "singleline".how should i do?